# Is simultaneous use of silicone gel and plaster against scar reasonable?

Tags: dermatology, scar-tissue-scars, plastic-surgery

Some plastic surgeons say that attaching silicone plaster on top of the silicone gel is more effective against scar. Some surgeons say that it is useless. What is the truth?